# Debugging a native android app in Eclipse

Tags: android, debugging, android-ndk, fopen

I am trying to debug a native application written in Android.
I took Android's Teapot NDK sample and added the following line.

```
FILE* fp = fopen("/sdcard/out","a");
```

If I keep a breakpoint in that line, the breakpoint is hit, but I am not able do "step in-to" the fopen function call.

There are other functions in the teapot sample code, where I am able to "step-into" at a breakpoint, but I am not able to "step-into" the fopen function.

Any ideas why? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Because fopen is part of the C standard library.  It isn't part of the code you downloaded, its part of a system library that you don't have code for.

Comment: isn't there any way by which I can step into it? any workaround?

Comment: Why do you want to?  I assure you fopen is working, if you have a problem its in the data you're passing it (likely the KitKat SD card changes or a bad path).  You're talking about probably the most used library on the planet.  If you just want to see the error, look at errno (fopen returns NULL on failure and sets the error in errno).

Comment: Well the thing is i have an fopen followed by an fwrite. The file gets created, but no content is getting written. Hence I want to trace through both fopen and fwrite to see what is going wrong.

Comment: If the file gets created (and wasn't there before) fopen worked.  If it didn't work, your fwrite would probably crash because you used a NULL file pointer (you are checking the return of fopen for NULL, right?).  But I pretty much assure you the problem isn't in the fxxx functions, its in your code.  You're probably best off posting your code as a question.  Are you checking the return value of fwrite, by the way?  It tells you the number of bytes written.  Also, if you're looking at the file and expecting it to be there immediately, add an fflush call.

Comment: Basically don't be so quick to jump into a debugger in complicated C system libraries.  There are tools to tell what happened-  the return values, errno, and perror.  Use them first, they're FAR quicker than debugging the functions.